# À quoi est due la coexistence de « clore » et « fermer » ?

Tags: étymologie, latin

Je ne comprends pas [l'étymologie de « fermer »](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fermer#Fran%C3%A7ais):

> [1.] Du latin *[firmare](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/firmo#la)* (« [affermir](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/affermir), solidifier », d’où «
> [fortifier](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fortifier) »),
> le glissement de sens vers celui de «
> [clore](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/clore) » a pu se faire
> dès le bas latin d’autant que son dérivé,
> *[confirmare](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/confirmo#la)*, est en relation sémantique avec
> *[sera](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sera#la)*, *[vectis](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vectis#la) portarum* (« les barres, les verrous des portes »). En latin médiéval, on note :
> *[archa](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/archa) firmata* (« coffre fermé »). ***Fermer*** et
> *clore* ont coexisté jusqu’à ce que ce dernier entre, par certaines de ses formes, en collision homonymique avec
> *[clouer](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/clouer)* et se réduise progressivement à certains emplois techniques.
>
> Ce, d’autant que le français connait un phénomène généralisé (→ voir *[solutionner](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/solutionner)*) et ancien (→ voir
> *[feinter](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/feinter)*) de remplacement des verbes des second et troisième groupes par des
> équivalents ou des dérivés du premier groupe.

Comment *clore* et *fermer* ont-ils commencé à coexister ? Qu'est-ce qui déclenché cette coexistence de *clore* et *fermer* ?

Comment: Il me semble que "fermer" n'est rien d'autre que "clore avec du fer". Du coup, ça ne m'étonne pas plus que ça d'apprendre que les deux ont coexisté

Comment: sans parler de l'italier dans lequel fermare signifie "arreter"

Comment: Tu donnes la réponse dans ta question, à savoir que les deux coexistaient déjà en latin dans des sens spécifiques différents puis ont évolué, fermer prenant petit à petit à lui le sens de clore, principalement pour éviter la confusion avec certaines formes de clouer.

Comment: @SteffX ça n'a pas de rapport avec le fer, ça vient plutôt du latin firmatus, avec pour sens dérivé: fermé.

Comment: @Laure SO Ce n'est pas ça, c'est plus complexe. Les 2 ne coexistaient pas en latin avec ce sens. Si j'ai le temps, je ferai une explication.